# What's the point of the X-Frame-Options header?

Tags: security, iframe, web, x-frame-options

I work on an application where users can embed their website within surrounding content by loading it in an iframe. This obviously relies on the X-Frame-Options not being set on the users website to work. I was asked by a client to create a reverse proxy because they didn't want to remove the X-Frame-Options header from their site for security concerns.

I setup the proxy and everything works but what's the point of the X-Frame-Options header if its as simple as creating a proxy to circumvent?

I understand the header exists to prevent clickjacking but if anyone can just make a proxy to workaround it... does it really increase security?

I don't come from the enterprise dev world, can you help me understand the reasoning behind why the IT department would be resistant to removing the header?

I noticed google.com and facebook.com also set the header, so it can't be completely pointless can it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any site served over http can have its content altered by using a proxy for example. So yes this is fairly pointless on http sites since it's so easily defeated.

Serving a site over https prevents this unless you have a proxy server which also intercepts https traffic. This is only possible by the proxy acting as a man-in-the-middle (MITM) so it decrypts the traffic at the proxy and then re-encrypts the traffic to send on to the server and same in way back. For this to work the proxy server either needs to know the server private key or, more likely, replaces the cert presented to its client with its own copy.

While MITM is usually associated with attacks there are some legitimate scenarios (though many argue even these are not legitimate and https should be secure!):

1. Anti-virus software can do this to scan requests to protect your computer. If you run Avast for example and have SSL scanning turned on (think it's on by default) and go to https://www.google.com and look at the cert you will notice it's been issued by Avast instead of by Google as usual. To do this requires the antivirus software to have installed an issuer certificate on your PC from which it can issue these replacement certs which your browser will still accept as real certs. Installing this issuer cert requires Admin access which you temporarily give when installing the anti-virus software.
2. Corporate proxies do a similar process to allow them to monitor https traffic from its employees. Again it requires an issuer installed on the PC using admin rights.

So basically it's only possible to use a proxy like you suggest for https traffic if you already have, or have had in the past, Admin rights in the PC - at which case all bets are off anyway.

The only other way to do this is to keep traffic on http using a proxy. For example if you request www.google.com then this normally redirects to https://www.google.com but your proxy can intercept that redirect request and instead keep the client->proxy connection on https, allowing the proxy to amend the request to strip out headers. This depends on the users not typing https, not noticing there is no green padlock and can be defeated with technologies like HSTS (which is automatically preloaded in some browsers for some sites like google.com). So not really reliable way to intercept traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Many secure sites use X-Frame-Options to prevent clickjacking

- [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking)
- [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

This prevents attackers from tricking users through transparent layers from performing actions they are unaware of on sites they didn't even know they loaded. Furthermore, this attack only works with frames that are directly served from the attacked/victim site's domain in the user's browser.

You may think that you can just reverse proxy the site and remove the frame busting header. But your proxy is not receiving or sending the end users cookies to the victim site. These secure sites rely on an active session, and as such will interpret the request from the proxy as coming from an unauthenticated user completely defeating the point of clickjacking.